# Standard list of religions for dropdown menu

Tags: forms, lists, html, drop-down-list

I am creating a form that will include a step about the person's religion, I have seen forms that contain a dropdown menu of religions, however I cannot find one which has a standard list of religions, basically it should have about 10-20 different major religions, including an exclusive option of "other" if their religion is not in the list.

Is there one where I can use for my website form?

Comment: What are you asking for, just a list of 20 religions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search found a Wikipedia page with [religions ranked by number of adherents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations). That seems as good a list as any. Just define your cutoff number for minimum popularity and you have your list.

Comment: I couldn't find any resources to back it up, but it might be interesting to think about this list through the filter of internet penetration by religion, or by the geographic regions that the form will be distributed in.

Answer (score 2):

check the web [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/) . In this webpage on the left side you can find the religion finder. You can use that for your reference... as it is coming from a authentic source "BBC"... So, more or less it is appropriate and correct.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="">
  <option value="">-- select one --</option>
  <option value="African Traditional & Diasporic">African Traditional & Diasporic</option>
  <option value="Agnostic">Agnostic</option>
  <option value="Atheist">Atheist</option>
  <option value="Baha'i">Baha'i</option>
  <option value="Buddhism">Buddhism</option>
  <option value="Cao Dai">Cao Dai</option>
  <option value="Chinese traditional religion">Chinese traditional religion</option>
  <option value="Christianity">Christianity</option>
  <option value="Hinduism">Hinduism</option>
  <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
  <option value="Jainism">Jainism</option>
  <option value="Juche">Juche</option>
  <option value="Judaism">Judaism</option>
  <option value="Neo-Paganism">Neo-Paganism</option>
  <option value="Nonreligious">Nonreligious</option>
  <option value="Rastafarianism">Rastafarianism</option>
  <option value="Secular">Secular</option>
  <option value="Shinto">Shinto</option>
  <option value="Sikhism">Sikhism</option>
  <option value="Spiritism">Spiritism</option>
  <option value="Tenrikyo">Tenrikyo</option>
  <option value="Unitarian-Universalism">Unitarian-Universalism</option>
  <option value="Zoroastrianism">Zoroastrianism</option>
  <option value="primal-indigenous">primal-indigenous</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```